# Creating a 2D Line Branch 

Tags: xna, c#

I'm looking into creating a 2D line branch, something for a "lightning effect". I did ask this question before on creating a "lightning effect" (mainly though referring to the process of the glow & after effects the lightning has & to whether it was a good method to use or not);
[Methods of Creating a "Lightning" effect in 2D](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/23000/methods-of-creating-a-lightning-effect-in-2d)

However i never did get around to getting it working. So i've been trying today to get a seconded attempt going but i'm getting now-were :/.

So to be clear on what i'm trying to-do, in this article posted;
http://drilian.com/2009/02/25/lightning-bolts/

I'm trying to create the line segments seen in the images on the site. I'm confused mainly by this line in the pseudo code;

```
// Offset the midpoint by a random amount along the normal.
midPoint += Perpendicular(Normalize(endPoint-startPoint))*RandomFloat(-offsetAmount,offsetAmount);
```

If someone could explain this to me it would be really grateful :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That line gets a unit vector (vector of length 1) from `startPoint` to `endPoint`

```
Normalize(endPoint-startPoint)
```

then gets a vector perpendicular to that (i.e. at right angles to the line)

```
Perpendicular(Normalize(endPoint-startPoint))
```

then multiplies it by some amount with a range (+ve or -ve).

```
* RandomFloat(-offsetAmount,offsetAmount)
```

It then adds this to `midPoint` thereby offsetting it.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, really helped clear things up for me :)

Answer (score 1):

I also tryied to implement "lighting" effect into my engine and my part of code for your problem is follows:

```
Random rand=new Random();
Vector3 dir = Vector3.Normalize(segment.endPoint - segment.startPoint);
midPoint += new Vector3(dir.Y, -dir.X, 0) *(float)(rand.NextDouble()*(offsetAmount*2)-offsetAmount);
```

Trick is hidden here:

```
  new Vector3(dir.Y, -dir.X, 0)
```

This creates normal vector, witch is perpendicular.

Comment: what time you feel was best for your offsetAmount?