# How to create glowing line with andengine?

Tags: andengine, effect

today I have played this game and still wondering about this effect: when I touch the target, some lines will appear (as those yellow lines in the image). How could I create this effect in andengine. In more detail, I want to create effect lines like that, I have no clue about methods they used.
[image]

Comment: Doesn't seem like its glowing to me, seems just a regular sprite with a texture previously made to look like that..

Comment: Yes, I did think so, however I found not any bitmap in resource. Would you give me hints?

Comment: The ones that look like lightning? Does [this](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/71397/how-can-i-generate-a-lightning-bolt-effect) or [this question](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/23000/methods-of-creating-a-lightning-effect-in-2d?rq=1) help?